# Definite article before adjective + noun phrases

Tags: adjectives, definite-article

This question may seem very elementary, but because I have very problem in using "**the**", I like to get an admission

I have the following sentence:

> We try to simulate the way a user finds the desired data by scanning and blocking the page based on **[the?]** textual delimiters.

Can we use "the" before **adjective** noun phrases with this reason that the adjective makes the noun specific? Is it such a rule?

I mean for example "the textual delimiters" (not other type of delimiters). However, I guess it could be sated without "the" too, in that case what it means which would be different with its meaning with "the"?

Comment: What do you mean the adjective makes the noun specific? Which adjective?

Comment: @pazzo, yes I guessed so! if they do, then I thought its OK to use "the" before the phrase!!?

Comment: It is not the function of adjectives to make make nouns more specific.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a significant difference here. If you use the definite article *the* you're talking about specific *textual delimiters* used to block the site. Without the article you're simply stating how you're blocking the site (through the use of *textual delimiters*).

Allow me to clarify the difference through a simpler sentence:

> - The cat often steals children's toys.
> - The cat often steals the children's toys.

In the first sentence you say that the cat often steals toys that are normally used by children. The second sentence however, states that the cat often steals toys that belong to specific children that were either talked about earlier or are known in the context.

The difference in your sentence is the same. Are you talking about the *use of textual delimiters in general*? Then use the zero article. Are you talking about the *use of specific textual delimiters*? Then use the definite article *the*.

Comment: Thank you, I specially asked about using "the" before adjective + noun phrases. What if I want to speak about "the textual delimiters" meaning not "the visual delimiters". I don't mean a specific textual delimiters, but I mean "the textual  ----- delimiters". However I think I  meant it without "the". I asked it in general about adjective constructions and your example wasn't in that direction.

Comment: If you're just trying to make a distinction between *textual delimiters* and *visual delimiters*, it does not matter which article you use. The word *textual* or *visual* already specifies the 'type' of *delimiters*.

Comment: However, if you want to emphasize the fact that the delimiters are *not textual* you could say: *...non-visual textual delimiters*.

Comment: Thank you, it seems the adjective when they are definitive doesn't need a "the", and using "the" would mean a known (or mentioned) ones. For example "black color" = "the black color" and the is extra

Comment: The definite article *the* **does not** modify the adjective. It modifies the noun. The adjective also modifies the noun. Articles never modify adjectives, since adjectives never take an article. Articles only modify nouns or noun phrases.