# When to use articles before adjectives?

Tags: articles, adjectives

I am struggling a bit with when I need to use a/an/the before adjective followed by a noun. I understand the rules for articles in general but I discovered that this particular case is always confusing me. For example, I wrote a sentence:

> The key to successful business development in this industry is understanding the market from regional perspective as Canada is a large country with different local dynamics.

Do I need articles before "successful", "regional", and "different"? It doesn't sound right to me. Another example is:

> The proof of their success is evident in acquisition interest by larger players and ongoing creation of smaller companies by their former employees.

Do I need articles before "acquisition", "larger", and "smaller"?

Comment: These questions of mine may be helpful : http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/59909/definite-article-before-adjective-noun-phrases and http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/64067/can-adjectives-make-a-noun-definite

Answer (score 2):

> The key to **successful business development** in this industry is understanding the market from ***a* regional perspective** as Canada is a large country with **different local dynamics**.

*successful business development* is an unspecific activity, so no article is used.

*regional perspective* is one of several possible perspectives (views), so I would use *a*.

*dynamics* is plural, so no article.

> The proof of their success is evident in **acquisition interest** by **larger players** and ongoing creation of **smaller companies** by their former employees.

*interest* here would be one of several "interests", or "interest" in general. So optional article use here.

*larger players* and *smaller companies* are plural so no article.

Comment: Plurals do not exclude the use of a definite article. **the larger players** would be acceptable as it would be specific but smaller companies is not specific.

Comment: What do you mean by an unspecific activity?  When some thing is unspecific we use a/an, right?

Comment: @user541396 There are many activities that make up "development". And they can be different from one case to another. Using "development" by itself cannot tell you what they are, therefore the term itself is not specific.

Answer (score 2):

Adjectives before a noun do not change any of the rules about whether you use articles or not.  Make this decision based on how the noun is being used.

> We needed some type of liquid for our experiment, we decided water would be best.  (No article because noun answers the question "which kind/type" and doesn't refer to an actual instance of anything.)
>
> We needed some type of liquid for our experiment, we decided sharp-tasting balsamic vinegar would be best.  (Same thing.  Adjectives "sharp-tasting" and "balsamic" don't change the reason why we don't use an article.)

So just ignore the adjective.

Answer (score 0):

In you first sentence, **a** is needed before "regional"

> ...from **a** regional perspective...

it is **a** and not **the** since it is understood there are several regions.

> The key to successful business development in this industry...

is fine, but necessarily a mouth-full (long)

The bare bones of your sentence is

> The key to ... development ... is ... from ***a*** ... perspective.

In your second sentence **the** might be used before "acquisition" and "ongoing" (or not) to create parallel construction, and I would choose different prepositions

> The proof of their success is evident **by** ***the*** acquisition interest **of** larger players and ***the*** ongoing creation of smaller companies by their former employees.
>
> The proof of their success is evident in acquisition interest **by** larger players and ongoing creation of smaller companies by their former employees.